# Click on image JavaScript detecting multiple clicks per actual click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below Javascript that prints the coordinates of the location that the user has clicked:

```
$(document).bind('click', function () {
                            $('#clickimage').bind('click', function (ev) {
                                var $img = $(ev.target);
                                var offset = $img.offset();
                                var x = ev.clientX - offset.left;
                                var y = ev.clientY - offset.top;
                                var div = document.getElementById('clicklocations');
                                div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'clicked at x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y + '<br>';
                            });
                        });
```

This works however every time the user clicks it prints an extra number of times, so for example I clicked four times and it prints:

```
clicked at x: 225.5, y: 149
clicked at x: 151.5, y: 117
clicked at x: 151.5, y: 117
clicked at x: 321.5, y: 175
clicked at x: 321.5, y: 175
clicked at x: 321.5, y: 175
clicked at x: 241.5, y: 251
clicked at x: 241.5, y: 251
clicked at x: 241.5, y: 251
clicked at x: 241.5, y: 251
```

Comment: That's not the way to bind click events. Remove image click handler out of the document click handler. And why do you need document click handler? Did you meant document.ready ?

Comment: Please, can you post the HTML involved ?

Comment: instead of `var $img = $(ev.target);` use `var $img = $(this);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).bind('click', function () {
                            $('#clickimage').bind('click', function (ev) {
                                var $img = $(ev.target);
                                var offset = $img.offset();
                                var x = ev.clientX - offset.left;
                                var y = ev.clientY - offset.top;
                                var div = document.getElementById('clicklocations');
                                div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'clicked at x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y + '<br>';
                            });
                        });
```

each click is binding an extra click on the document thus the behavior.

remove `document.bind("click"`

and only keep this

```
$('#clickimage').bind('click', function (ev) {
                                var $img = $(ev.target);
                                var offset = $img.offset();
                                var x = ev.clientX - offset.left;
                                var y = ev.clientY - offset.top;
                                var div = document.getElementById('clicklocations');
                                div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'clicked at x: ' + x + ', y: ' + y + '<br>';
                            });
```

or put it inside `document.ready` function

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see repeated outputs generated by event listeners, the first thing you should suspect is you have bound listener to the same event multiple times. And in your case you are doing that.

Each time a click is fired on your document, 1 more listener is attached to your #clickimage

Therefore the repetition grows with each click